# SEGMENTATION_FAULT

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  int take_photo = 0;
  char command[8];
  char * pictures = "take_pictures";

  strcpy(command, pictures);
  if (strcmp(command, "take_pictures") == 0) {
    printf("%s\n", "CLICK_PHOTO_TAKEN");
    take_photo = 1;
  } else {
    printf("%s\n", "SEG_FAULT_NO_PHOTO");
  }
  return 0;

}
```

Can someone tell me why I keep getting a `SEGMENTATION FAULT` error?
It looks perfectly fine to me

Might have something to do with the array

Comment: `strlen("take_pictures") > 7`. You are overflowing the `command` buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the segfault at this line:

```
strcpy(command, pictures);
```

The string `command` is too small. You're trying to copy a long string to it. [The behavior is undefined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy).

You can fix this by making `command` larger. For example,

```
char command[32];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was overthinking it by a lot I'm not very fluent in C